# Convert .skp file to .dae using C++

Tags: c++, file-format, sketchup

Hi I am trying to convert **.skp** files to **.dae** using [this](https://github.com/olilej/StdSkpExporterCall) code.But all the time I keep getting **Exporter and Handle as undefined**, I don't know why. Does anybody have any idea about how to resolve this ?

Here's the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <WinBase.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "slapi\import_export\modelexporterplugin.h"

typedef SketchUpModelExporterInterface* (*GetExporterPtr)(void);

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 0)
        return 0;

HINSTANCE Handle = LoadLibrary("Exporters/skp2dae.dll");

if (!Handle)
    return -1;

GetExporterPtr ExporterPtr = (GetExporterPtr)GetProcAddress(Handle,"GetSketchUpModelExporterInterface");
SketchUpModelExporterInterface* Exporter = ExporterPtr();

if (Exporter->GetFileExtensionCount() > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        const std::string input_skp(argv[i]);
        const std::string output = input_skp + "." + Exporter->GetFileExtension(0);
        Exporter->ConvertFromSkp(input_skp, output, NULL, NULL);
    }
}
FreeLibrary(Handle);
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might get a better answer if you posted some code in your question instead of an unreadable screen shot.

Comment: I already gave the link for the project. Anyways posted the code here also.

Comment: It looks to me like your watch is out of context.  If Handle is null because LoadLibrary fails your code would never get to the highlighted line.  Have you set a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: Yes I set a break point and it comes inside the if condition but never runs the for loop and using watch i try to find out the values of `Exporter->GetFileExtension(0) ,input_skp and output` but unable to find out. I tried to refresh the watch values but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null handle here:

```
HINSTANCE Handle = LoadLibrary("Exporters/skp2dae.dll");
```

which suggests that your application can't find the DLL.  I think you have to use a backslash on Windows.

Try

```
HINSTANCE Handle = LoadLibrary("Exporters\\skp2dae.dll");
```

However, I don't understand how your code gets to the if statement as a null Handle should return -1.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx.